# React Native Firebase Messaging Registering For Remote Messaging Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting contradictory error messages from `"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.6.2",`

### First Error:

> [Error: [messaging/unregistered] You must be registered for remote
> messages before calling getToken, see
> messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages().]

Okay easy enough let's "registerDeviceForRemoteMessages" before calling "getToken".

### Code:

```
export const fetchMessagingToken = async (uid) => {
  await messaging()
    .registerDeviceForRemoteMessages()
    .then(async () => {
      await messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then((token) => {
          return saveTokenToUser(uid, token);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("FETCH MESSAGING TOKEN ERROR:", error);
    });
};
```

### Second Error/WARN:

> WARN  Usage of "messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages()" is not
> required. You only need to register if auto-registration is disabled
> in your 'firebase.json' configuration file via the
> 'messaging_ios_auto_register_for_remote_messages' property.

I don't have a `firebase.json` file in my project, som I'm a bit confused here. I can't seem to update my users device token. This was working as expected in `"expo": "~49.0.15"` however after updating to `"expo": "^50.0.7"` seems to be issues.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/6829